# Обнаружение аномалий в данных

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение

У меня имеется огромный объем данных, который включает в себя около 500 признаков следующего вида:
file = pd.read_csv('X_train.csv')

```
                     признак1               признак 2           п.3  \
0                         0.400000                   1.0           0.0   
1                         0.700000                   1.0           0.0   
2                         0.800000                   1.0           0.0   
3                         0.100000                   1.0           0.0   
4                         0.388889                   0.0           1.0   
...                            ...                   ...           ...   
37307                     0.666667                   0.0           1.0   
37308                     0.477778                   0.0           1.0   
37309                     0.666667                   1.0           0.0   
37310                     0.500000                   0.0           1.0   
37311                     0.300000                   0.0           0.0   

                         п.4                                  п.5\
0                        0.0                                  0.0   
1                        0.0                                  0.0   
2                        0.0                                  0.0   
3                        0.0                                  0.0   
4                        0.0                                  0.0   
...                      ...                                  ...   
37307                    0.0                                  0.0   
37308                    0.0                                  0.0   
37309                    0.0                                  0.0   
37310                    0.0                                  0.0   
37311                    0.0                                  1.0
```

Моя задача зафиксировать аномалии на этой выборке (c учителем). Но мне достались данные категориальные данные, по которым прошлись *one hot encoder*. Теперь находить зависимости между признаками стало намного сложнее. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие методы нужно использовать для нахождения аномалий для подобного типа данных? Стоит ли их видоизменять?

Answer (score 0):

- "Поиск аномалий" вообще достаточно широкая тема, там можно применить [много разных методов](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html)
- То, что данные преобразованы OHE, позволит вам использовать простые методы вроде линейной регрессии, но затруднит анализ полученных результатов - аномалии то вы найдёте, но как вы их будете интерпретировать, если не будете знать, что это за признак?
- Я бы предложил начать с *линейной регрессии* (или *логистической регрессии* - смотря какого типа у вас целевая переменная, вы вроде не сказали). Просто натренируйте LR на ваших данных, а потом попытайтесь их же предсказать. Те точки данных, на которых LR будет сильно ошибаться при этом и будут аномалиями. Но это не точно.

P.S. После уточнения автора вопроса выяснилось, что имеется в виду обычная задача классификации. Для такой задачи рекомендуется обычный Data Science процесс EDA:

- Построить статистики для переменных (хотя бы основных, если переменных много)
- Построить графики (или карту) зависимости переменных между собой и признаков с  целевой переменной
- Пробовать методы машинного обучения начиная с самых простых и постепенно усложняя

Comment: Целевая переменная class, в которой 1 - аномалия, 0 - норма

Comment: @ИльяПетров Погодите, так тогда это обычная задача классификации получается. Для классификации тоже есть множество методов в том же scikit-learn, просто пробуйте какие себя лучше покажут.

Comment: какую аналитику стоит произвести для данных, перед тем, как закидывать ее на обучение?